# How to install a python package globally with manual setup.py?

Tags: python, ubuntu, setup.py

I am trying to install a python package with setup.py that I had written.The setup.py looks like this:

```
    from setuptools import setup
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'pyduino',
    description = 'PyDuino project aims to make python interactive with hardware particularly arduino.',
    url = '###',
    keywords = 'python arduino',
    author = '###',
    author_email = '###',
    version = '0.0.0',
    license = 'GNU',
    packages = ['pyduino'],
    install_requires = ['pyserial'],
    classifiers = [

        # How mature is this project? Common values are
        #   3 - Alpha
        #   5 - Production/Stable
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools', 
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    ],
    scripts=['pyduino/pyduino.py'],
)
```

But this package installs in the directory /usr/local/bin.I can't import the modules of the package in other directories.Is there any way to install it globally and I can use in all directories? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Your code is **only** the given script? Moreover should that be a *script* or a *package*/*module*? If you specify to `setup` a module/package it will be put in place where you can import it from everywere. However scripts are **not** meant to be importable, they are meant to be *executed*.

Comment: I can import the module **pyduino** in /usr/local/bin but not in other directories.If i set the path to /usr/local/bin then import error doesn't occur.But I don't want to set the path everytime.So,is there anyway to install so that I can use my modules?

Comment: Yes I understand that. My question is: `pyduino` is a **script** or a **module**? If you want to import it from any location then it is a module and you should use `py_modules=['pyduino/pyduino.py']` instead of using `scripts=...`.

Comment: Yeah..I am sorry.It is a script.It has a class pyduino.I want to import that class from pyduino.py.So,how can I do that?

Comment: As I said: if you have a module you want to import from everywhere you just have to put it under `py_modules` or `packages` if it is inside a package. If this still isn't clear I suggest that you clarify in the question **all** the files you are dealing with, how they are structured in directories/packages/modules and what you want to obtain as a final result when installing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to have your package installed the same way as with pip install command.

at first you need to have a proper setup.py, for example:

```
import setuptools

packages = setuptools.find_packages(where='./src')

setuptools.setup(
    name="the_utility",
    version="1.0",
    packages=packages,
    include_package_data=True,
    description="Utility to execute command",
    long_description=open("README.md", "r").read(),
    package_dir={pkg: f"src/{pkg.replace('.', '/')}" for pkg in packages},
    install_requires=[line.strip() for line in open('requirements.txt', 'r').readlines()],
    extras_require={},
    classifiers=[],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'command_1 = module_dir.cli:function_1'
        ]
    })
```

Then, you have to run `python setup.py install` command. Then you will have your package available from terminal comand line everywhere, except some virtual envs